# Excel Function For If Then Statement for Range of Times

Tags: excel, function, excel-2010

=IF(I44<"0:01","0",IF(I44<"0:30","2:00",IF(I44<"1:00","2:30",IF(I44<"1:30","3:00",IF(I44<"2:00","3:30",IF(I44<"2:30","4:00",IF(I44<"3:00","4:30",IF(I44<"3:30","5:00",IF(I44<"4:00","5:30",IF(I44<"4:30","6:00",IF(I44<"5:00","6:30",IF(I44<"5:30","7:00",IF(I44<"6:00","7:30",IF(I44<"6:30","8:00",IF(I44<"7:00","8:30",IF(I44<"7:30","9:00",IF(I44<"8:00","9:30",IF(I44<"8:30","10:00",IF(I44<"9:00","10:30",IF(I44<"9:30","11:00",IF(I44<"10:00","11:30","")))))))))))))))))))))

(Left out the code tags so you dont have to scroll 30 pages to the right)

I am using this function to add specific amounts of time to specific range of time and this seems like there must be a better method of doing this.

For example: for a input time of < 30 min, would output 2:00 hr, for input time of < 1:00 would output 2:30 ... and for each 30 min increment in the input the output would increment by 30 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps just round down to the next half hour then add 2 hours, i.e

`=IF(I44=0,0,FLOOR(I44,"0:30")+"2:00")`

[with an IF to deal with zero values]

Format result cell as a time value, e.g. h:mm or similar